# Airflow PostgreSQL sqlalchemy

Tags: airflow, version, compatibility

My question: How to install setup Airflow on Python virtual machine?

With

- Airflow 2.8.1
- Postgres 15 and 16
- SQLAlchemy 2.0.27

I get this error:

```
  File "/home/bigdata/airflow/afvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1734, in parse_user_argument_for_enum

    raise exc.ArgumentError(f"Invalid value for '{name}': {arg!r}")

  sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Invalid value for 'executemany_mode': 'values'
```

Comment: Airflow doesn't support/tested on SQLAlchemy 2 yet, see related [issue/task](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/28723). Please follow [Installation from PyPI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html) for install compatible libraries